# How to create Form On Top and cannot access other forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Currently I have two forms(Form1 (base form) and Form2), from form1 I open form2, I want form1 to be inaccessible (unable to click buttons and access any other objects on that form) while form 2 is still open, and once form2 is closed I can access form1 again, I don't know what this behavior is called

I know how to put the form always on top via `newForm.TopMost = true` and how to check if a form is open via `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Alert_Form>().Any()`, Anyone know the sniplet I need to achieve what I want for form1 and possible (any other form)

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply call ShowDialog on your Form2 instance rather than Show.  That will display a modal dialogue, which is the behaviour that you describe.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for, Here is my code: newForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: Don't forget to flag this response as an answer if it does indeed answer your question successfully.

Comment: Yeah I did, Theres just a cooldown for 11 minutes -was waiting for it to finish-
Thanks again and cheers mate =)